# Pandas install-Importing the multiarray numpy extension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to install pandas using pip3, but the install fails.  I've reinstalled numpy as the error recommends, but it didn't help.  A Google search failed to turn up a solution for me.

I have installed:

- Python 3.6.5-1
- numpy 1.14.4

I'm using "pip3 install pandas", and it's trying to install pandas 0.23.0.  Here's the error:

```
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: Could not load module /QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so.
    The local-exec model was used for thread-local
       storage, but the module is not the main program.
Examine the .loader section header with the 'dump -Hv' command.
```

Comment: I always recommend `conda` over `pip`. Seems to never run into errors like this

Comment: I'm starting to suspect the problem is with numpy.  I have other things that are failing to install, and they all point to numpy.  I'll look and see if I can find a conda for my platform.  I guess it can't hurt.